# Registering when someone reads a list item

Tags: workflow, custom-list, tasks

Just want to throw a challenge in the hope that someone else has done this.

We are just upgrading from sharepoint 2007 to Sharepoint 2013 and replicating process we do currently.  We have a process where communications are shared with large audiences through Exchange Dl's using a custom list.  It has an audience tic box and dependant on the combination determines who receives the email.    When a new communication is approved a workflow kicks in and emails everyone to say "new comm".

When they click the link in the workflow email it takes them to the dispform.aspx of that comm and in the header and footer there is a hyperlink saying "click here when read".  This then takes them to another custom list which has a field looking up at the comms title (from the pr virus custom list) and has fields saying "Have you read nad understood?" And a field that says "Give us some feedback"

Works great today....we output the data to a database and do our reporting.

The challenge is we can't track who got what commmunication and should have read it...we know who has read it e.g. 10 people,from team A red it....but we don't know that it was sent to 20 people in team A so 50% have read it.

Been thinking we could setup SP/AD Groups to send the workflow email to rather than exchange DL's and rather than a hyperlink on the dispform.aspx of the comm to another custom list, we assign a task to the users.

That way we will know that the comm email was sent to X number of people...

Trick and the help we need is can you assign a task to a SP group, and when assigned can we get them to say "read and understood" or " Read and not understood" rather than the traditional approved & rejected.

The task can just stand there waiting for everyone to complete..

What we are trying to achieve is just the volume of people sent it v's read....

Hope this makes sense any guidance you can give - we are using standard SP2013 (no info path)

Comment: The task process holds a count of how many tasks were assigned `[%Task Process:Assigned Task Count%]` and how many tasks were completed `[%Task Process:Completed Task Count%]`

Answer (score 0):

**You can edit the list item View form and add a Script Editor WebPart.**

On the Edit page -> select the Insert Web Part tab from the Ribbon -> From the Categories menu -> select Media and Content and then Script Editor from the Parts menu

**Inside that use SharePoint JavaScript Object model to capture the current logged in user information.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
var clientContext;
function init(){
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = oWeb.get_currentUser();
    clientContext.load(currentUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    //currentUser.get_loginName(); 
    //currentUser.get_id();
    //currentUser.get_title();
    //currentUser.get_email();
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

**Next store this information into a hidden list.**

1. Start by opening your SharePoint site in SharePoint Designer. In the navigation bar on the left hand side, click on the List and Libraries entry.
2. In the main window, the Lists and Document Libraries associated with the site are displayed. Click on the name of the specific List you wish to hide.
3. This will bring you to a management page for that List.
4. In the Settings section, there is another section marked `General Settings`. Ensure the check box marked `Display this list on the Quick Launch` is unchecked. Check the box labeled `Hide from browser`. This will hide the List or Document Library from SharePoint’s UI.

   ```
   var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

   function createListItem() {
       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
       var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');            
       var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
       this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);         
       oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
       oListItem.set_item('Body', 'Hello World!');         
       oListItem.update();
       clientContext.load(oListItem);          
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
   }

   function onQuerySucceeded() {
       alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
   }

   function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
       alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
   }
   ```

Comment: I like.  Not overly familiar with JavaScript Amal.  How do I record this in the hidden list?   Can it also record the "commmunication title" (a field in the list along with the person who viewed it?  very excited now!  Doesn't get us over the hump about knowing who the list item was emailed too either

Comment: Yes ... I provided samples code you can use in each steps.. You will get more excited if you start looking into CSR.. its easy to capture data using that..

Comment: Perfect.....googled CSR and lots of cool stuff.....how do I get this to write to a hidden list?

Comment: Check my last sampel code.. createListItem... you can modify that ... as of now it create a new item in Annoucements list with Title = My New Item! and Body = Hello World!

Comment: Ah...forgive the ignorance...love it!!!  Thanks for that will let you know how we go!!  Any suggestions for registering who it was emailed too?

Comment: I didn't quiet understand the email sending part.. which process is sending those email? Is it a custom workflow? Whatever process is sending you need to add your logic to insert the information into a similar audit list..

Comment: Really love Amal's solution but need some help if anyone can - where does the second bit of code go, and how do I get it to populate the "title" from the first list in the "title" field of the second list and the "username" of the person into the "body" field in the second lists?